# How load testing is done

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I am a newbie and want to ask how load testing is done by visual studio.What is the process behind test controller and agent.How virtual machines are able to access the files(.dll) required(If files are copied then where are they copied).

and

And how to equally distribute load among various test agents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Me too trying to explore Load Testing
I am using these resources**

http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nkamkolkar/archive/2010/11/02/getting-started-with-visual-studio-2010-ultimate-load-and-performance-testing.aspx

**Collection of links in this link**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2011/03/08/announcement-unlimited-load-testing-for-visual-studio-2010-ultimate-with-msdn-subscribers-now.aspx